# How Conditional Probability Works in a Sampling Experiment

Tags: probability

My textbook explains the conditional probability $$P(B|A)$$ is the probability that even B occurs in the reduced sample space A, as in the figure.

[image]

The book then gives the following example:

We randomly picks two television tubes from a shipment of 240 tubes of which 15 are defective. The probability that the first one is defective is $P(A)=15/240$ and the probability that the second one is defective given that the first one is defective is $P(B|A)=14/239$. Thus, the probability that both will be defective is $15/240 * 14/239$.

I don't understand how conditional probability works in that example, especially in regard to the above figure. More specifically,

1. What is the sample space in the experiment?
2. What is the reduced sample space in the experiment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the $240$ tubes of the shipment. Then

- $T = G \cup D$, where $G$ is the set of good ones and $D$ is the set of defective ones.
- It is given that $|D| = 15$, hence $|G| = 225$.
- The sample space is $S = \{(t_1, t_2)\; | t_1 \in T, t_2 \in T\setminus \{t_1\} \}$
- $A = \{(d, t)\; | d \in D, t \in T\setminus \{d\} \}$ - first one is defective
- $\Rightarrow P(A) = \frac{15\cdot 239}{240 \cdot 239} = \frac{15}{240}$
- $B = \{(t, d)\; | d \in D, t \in T\setminus \{d\} \}$ - second one is defective
- $A \cap B = \{(d_1, d_2)\; | d_1 \in D, d_2 \in D\setminus \{d_1\} \}$

Since you are dealing with $P(B|A)$, the reduced sample space is now $A$. This is so, because the conditional probability of $B$ given $A$ restricts the consideration only to events which are contained in $A$.

Now, in your example, they use the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ to calculate the probability of $B \cap A$:
$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} \Rightarrow P(B\cap A) = P(B|A)\cdot P(A) = \frac{14}{239}\cdot \frac{15}{240}$$